# start httpd from a customer's account

Tags: httpd

I am running a web server (apache, mysql, php, cpanel) and I faced with an issue that some users start the httpd server from their accounts. This causes huge overload.

Part of the `ps auxf` command:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND    
infor8 30135  0.0  0.0  28996  3372 ?        SN   08:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
infor8 30136  0.0  0.0  28996  3440 ?        SN   08:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
infor8 30137  0.0  0.0  28996  3364 ?        SN   08:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

There are actually hundreds of such processes from the `infor8` user. I am searching from which directory the process was started in the following way:

```
lsof -p 30135

perl    25631 infor8  cwd    DIR      8,3    4096 76735848 /home/infor8/public_html
perl    25631 infor8  rtd    DIR      8,3    4096        2 /
perl    25631 infor8  txt    REG      8,3 1184862 42976810 /usr/local/bin/perl
perl    25631 infor8  mem    REG      8,3   23736 63414584 /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
```

Using the 'maldet' malware scanner I have found (and removed) a lot of files like:

```
{HEX}php.sessmasq.renata.519 : ./images/a96b6.php
{HEX}php.sessmasq.renata.519 : ./images/7fec3.php
{HEX}php.sessmasq.renata.519 : ./images/b1d10.php
```

Could someone please assist of how to block running apache locally from the customers' accounts on the web server?

Thank you for any assistance.

---

Update:

Permissions for httpd:

```
root@server [~]# which /usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
root@server [~]# ll /usr/sbin/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 15  2008 /usr/sbin/httpd -> /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl*
root@server [~]# ll /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2971 Sep  9  2009 /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl*
root@server [~]#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the permissions or setting an ACL on httpd would be the simplest way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use ACL here. Could you please detail your answer regarding the permissions? Where should I change them?

Comment: On the file you don't want users to run. `chmod oa-x httpd` might work, but it all depends on how httpd is supposed to be invoked normally and how the group is set up.

Comment: Please check the updated post with the permissions info. Apache is configured to run virtual hosts on the server. Do you need any info more?

Comment: Test out removing other and everyone execute permissions on it, then. I can't guarantee it'll work with everything you have in your environment, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to remove read permission, not just execute permission.  Just because something's chmod -x, doesn't mean that you're unable to run it -- case in point:

> tuttle@mrdo:/tmp/foo$ ls
>
> hostname
>
> tuttle@mrdo:/tmp/foo$ ls -l
>
> total 16
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 tuttle tuttle 14688 2011-06-09 17:05 hostname
>
> tuttle@mrdo:/tmp/foo$ ./hostname
>
> bash: ./hostname: Permission denied
>
> tuttle@mrdo:/tmp/foo$ /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./hostname
>
> mrdo